# Extracting data from sqlback formatted file for conversion to CSV

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv

I have an sqback file respresenting an sqlite db file. I want to extract the data from this sqback file, ie, table names and contents, and convert it into csv file format. I want to do this using Java.

** The sqback file will have already been uploaded from android device to pc prior to processing. So I need a solution that is appropriate for taking place server side.

Does anyone have any leads on how to perform such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website indicates which extra libraries to make use of, as well as provides examples of how to interact with the sqlite files (http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC#Usage)

important things to note:

1) make sure to include load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader. This is done with the line

2) the sqlite file IS a db, even if its not sitting on a server somewhere. So you still must create a connection to the file to interact with it. And you must open the connection and close the connection as well. 
 `Connection connection = null;
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path); // path is a String to the sqlite file (sqlite or sqback) 
 connection.close(); // after you are done with the file`

3) Information can be extracted by using sql code to query the file. This returns a processable object of type ResultSet that holds your data pertaining to the query

```
  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
  statement.setQueryTimeout(30);
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tblName);
```

4) from the ResultsSet you can grab data using the get commands with either the column index or the column header key
`rs.getString("qo")`

Hope that helps anyone having the same issue as I was having

Answer (score 1):

If using Android you can take advantage of the built SQLiteDatabase and SQLiteOpenHelper. You'll find **all** the info you need [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

After parsing everything you can export to CSV the way you want by using [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html).

**EDIT:** So basically what you need to do is to parse the bytes by reading them and that way have access to the content. In some cases you don't even need to convert them to a String, since could be that you only need the value of the byte. (ie.: Offset: 44 Length:4 Description:The schema format number. Supported schema formats are 1, 2, 3, and 4.). 
You can always check if your values are correct with any HEX editor, even opening the sqlite file with a text editor of any kind would help.

Let's start from scratch. First, reading the file. Two approaches

- a. Read the whole file and parse it after
- b. Read and parse the whole file in blocks (recommended, specially for bigger files)

Both approaches would share most of the following code:

```
File file = new File("YOUR FILE ROUTE");
int len = 1024 * 512; //512KB

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    fis = null;
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] b = new byte[len];
int bread;

try {

    while((bread = fis.read(b, 0, len))!=-1)
    {
        if(parseBlock(b, bread)==1)
            return;
}

    fis.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The difference would be between getting partial blocks and parsing them on the fly (which I guess works for you) and getting the whole thing would be to just put:

```
fis.read(b, 0, fis.available);
```

Instead of the while loop.

Ultimately your approach is right, and that's the way to get bytes into a String. (new String(b)). Moreover the first characters are likely to represent weird symbols, if you have a look to the file format of SQL, these are reserved bytes for storing some metadata.
Open the sqlite file with any text editor and check that what you see there matches with what comes out of your code.

Comment: Thanks so much Jose. I guess I should have been a tad more specific. I just updated the question to include the fact that the sqback file is uploaded from the android device to a pc and so the parsing needs to happen server side.

Comment: Then you need to start reading bytes :) 
Use this as a reference (http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)
I'd recommend to use FileInputStream to read the file. It's interesting to set the blocks of bytes you read as a multiple of a power of 2 (something around 1024Kb or 512Kb tends to be the most proper options, in case your files reach that size). If you don't have experience at all with that I can give some example codes.

Comment: Thanks so much again, Jose. I really appreciate that. Im going to give it a read and a try this after noon and hopefully all will go smoothly. I will hit up this thread if I have more questions. 'Im new on SO and its already shaping up to be awesome.

Comment: I would love to take you up on your offer for a short example. Right now I am reading in bytes from my file into an array: byte [] b, and I am trying to write that the contents of b to a file in a meaningful way. To accomplish the transition between bytes into meaningful text I am using: String(b) and getting nowhere. I am getting symbols which shouldn't be (it looks like a box with an ear inside of it). I have tried also using the "ACSII" encoding but no luck. I do realize that this is a bit of a different problem.

Comment: I have also tried the following 3 encodings as specified in bytes 56 of the header file: byte b [] = new byte[512]; FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(fileName); inStream.read(b);             System.out.println("UTF-8" + new String(b, "UTF-8"));
System.out.println("UTF-16be" + new String(b, "UTF-16be"));
System.out.println("UTF-16le" + new String(b, "UTF-16le"));

Comment: Edited my post. Although your approach is right. You should be getting what is expected. Double check the link I sent you for SQLite file format. As you'll see, first bytes doesn't intend to represent any character. So it's completely expectable that any conversion may result in a weird character representation.

Comment: Thanks so much Jose. I actually ended up stumbling across this little gem. And it is working beautifully: http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC#Usage

Comment: Fantastic! Yeah, it was for sure that there would be some libraries for Java. We were just approaching it from the nerdy perspective :)